# My cart shows wrong subtotal and tax

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

My cart shows wrong subtotal and I think this is also affecting calculation of tax (20%). In the shopping cart and in the checkout, price displayed are correct but subtotal and total have no 20% VAT TAX effect on it.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you configured your tax by setting zones and rules ? Don't the prices already include tax ?

Comment: Probably because you are using some weird extension or changed something in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin panel you can set whether totals and prices are shown with/without tax, go to:

```
System->Configuration->Sales->Tax
```

Amongst other things, you can set

```
Display Prices
Display Subtotal
Display Shipping Amount
```

To be `including tax`, `excluding tax` or `including and excluding tax`, and

```
Include Tax In Grand Total
Display Full Tax Summary
Display Zero Tax Subtotal
```

to be `yes` or `no` for places like the cart, the invoice, etc.